# cant map over and fetch the data present inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios, next.js

I had an assignment which i was not able to do since i was busy but out of curiosity I am trying to do it. I have this api `https://dev-api.fitnessfuel360.com/app/home`
from which i am trying to get the items and the data present in it.
I am currently trying to use Nextjs in which axios is being used.
this is what my code looks like as of now.

```
//Index.js file where Base_url is the api
  const { items } = await axios.get(Base_URL);

    return {
        props: { items: items },
    };
}
```

I am then passing Items to the the component where i want to render out the data present inside of the items array.

```
//my productSection.js component
   <div>
                {items.map((items) => (
                    <h1>{items.slug}</h1>
                ))}
            </div>
```

However this gives me an error saying
`` Error: Error serializing `.items` returned from getServerSideProps in "/". Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value. ``

So how do i access the information inside of this Items array?
There were some points mentioned in the assignment as well like `object has 2 properties type and data. Type key decides which component to render and data will be passed to to the component`
and `Code should not throw error on invalid types in json`
I Have not used key to render out component before so this goes over my head.
Please understand that I am still a beginner so yeah, Please let me know what to do here and how to achieve this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: please post proper code and also format your question correctly

Answer (score 2):

`axios` return a response object with a `data` property, try to change your code like this

```
 const { data } = await axios.get(Base_URL);

    return {
        props: { items: data.items },
    };
}
```

Comment: ok now there is another error saying "Error: Error serializing `.items` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value. " it just keeps getting better... there are objects inside of the array for sure

Comment: @ManshulDuggal Can you please post the result of a `console.log(data)` to see the structure of the API response?